How can I play video with H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264) codec using <video> tag
I am writing angular app to stream videos returned from backend. These videos are live streams that I tested that work using VLC Media Player > Open Network Stream without any issues.
Codec returned looks like this:

I am using video html element where I set the src of source to returned link from the backend:
<video #videoPlayer id="video" preload="auto" muted>
 <source #videoSrc type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

Can I play videos with codec like this on web browsers?

Can I play videos with codec like this on web browsers? what happens when you try?

Nothing happens, video doesn't load. If I just pass link received directly as source, video element shows but doesn't load. Same streaming link works as expected in VLC Media Player. I have no idea what happens, I've been trying for days to make it work

How does the URL look like when you open the stream in VLC?
Can you dump a part of the stream to disk and share it?

cant you use hls.js ?

If your backend provides an .m3u8 URL, integrate hls.js into your Angular app.

Is it rtsp or which Protocol use the live Stream ?

@lukas23 (1) This is programming... It's not enough to just say "These videos are live streams" because the file format and playback platform matters. The codec H264 is fine for most browsers, so your browser (platform) doesn't like the data or file format of your stream... (2) How do you know you have a "live stream"? Are you making the files (live segments?) yourself, or actually just reading some data from another server? Does your backend send back video file bytes or it sends text (eg: a video file's URL)? What browser are you testing? What is the path look like?

might check chrome://media-internals/ for errors and include those in your question.

<video controls>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>

can You please check this.

With no details about the file and where it comes from, you will have to eliminate the issue.
Is the location http://127.0.0.1 involved in your project?
(1) Check that it's not a CORS issue or an error about mixing HTTP with HTTPS.
For this error checking, open the browser's Developer Tools and check the console tab.
(2) Make sure the file serving protocol is acceptable to web browsers.
Only https:// and wss:// is supported. You cannot use rtsp:// or ftp:// to feed a video tag. For situations where the URL (file path) has rtp or rtsp in the starting, then you need to use something like FFmpeg to both (1) read that RTSP link and (2) re-send same data to a HTTP location.
Let me know if it's still not working after checking the above steps...
